# Heroku PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: role "xxxxxxxxxxx" is not permitted to log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I created a new postgres database on Heroku for my Rails stack. The role seems to not work. I cannot tell if it's using an old role.

I tried to reset the database from the command line.

`heroku run rake db:setup`

I expected Heroku to setup the proper role to manage the database from the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rake db:setup` tries to create your database](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#setup-the-database) before loading your schema and seeding it. You [can't create a database this way using Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permissions):

> You cannot create or modify databases and roles on Heroku Postgres. The SQL below is for reference only.

Depending on your needs, you could run [`heroku pg:reset DATABASE`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-reset), where `DATABASE` is the name of an existing Postgres database, to drop and recreate that database followed by `heroku run db:schema:load` and `heroku run db:seed`. (You probably already have a database.)

If that's not a good fit you could [provision a Heroku Postgres database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres), then load your schema and seed it. But please bear in mind that you probably already have a database:

> Before you provision Heroku Postgres, confirm that it isn’t *already* provisioned for your app (Heroku automatically provisions Postgres for apps that include certain libraries, such as the `pg` Ruby gem).
>
> Use the `heroku addons` command to determine whether your app already has Heroku Postgres provisioned

Answer (score 0):

Check if your migrations are running properly. I ran into this issue because my Rails migrations were broken. Then try to push your changes through the Github/Heroku CI pipeline or however you setup your workflow. Don't try to use that heroku command, directly, like Chris said.